# Настройка компилятора c#

Tags: c#, компиляция, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте, я тут пытаюсь сделать так, что бы после компиляции не создавался файл exe, а выводилось сразу все в консоль(т.е. запуск файла). 
Пробовал сделать: csc test.cs && start test.exe, но такой способ не подходит:
Во-первых потому что он создает exe, во-вторых он создает второе консольное окно, а мне нужно что бы все в одном и том же окне происходило.

Пробую сделать все в редакторе sublime text 3, пишу вbuild system редактора: `"cmd": ["csc", "$file"]` - так он просто компилирует файл и выводит:

> "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1586.0 for C# 5
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. бла-бла...",

Может есть какие опции отвечающие за это или же что-то другое? Смотрел параметры самого компилятора, подобного не нашел. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Без exe'шника нельзя.

Comment: `C# Interactive` пробовали?

Comment: Bulson, нет, но вряд ли поможет в моем случае.